# Angular JS - Binding view and app.js - ng-repeat doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created a ASP.NET MVC 4 project by using Angular JS. I wouldn't be able to create a JSFiddle for this example of code.

I notice that I retrieve well the categories and it prints well. Then, when I click on one of the categories represented by a tag `'<a>'`, my code goes to `$scope.setActualItem` of my app.js and the ajax call retrieves the right datas. But the changes are not printed in my view. However, I use `"<div ng-repeat="p in products">"` to get datas from the controller.

Do you have a solution ?

Thank you

app.js :

```
var appli = angular.module("Demo", []);

appli.controller('CategoryCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
   $http.get('/Category/GetCategories')
        .success(
            function (data) {
              console.log(data);
              $scope.categories = data;
            }
         );

   $scope.setActualItem = function (index) {
      $scope.currentItem = $scope.categories[index];

      var idCat = $scope.currentItem.id;
      console.log("passe ici");
      $http.get('/Category/GetProductsByCategory/'+idCat)
           .success(
                function (data) {
                   console.log(data);
                   $scope.products = data;
                }
            );
    };
});
```

My View :

```
<html ng-app="Demo">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="CategoryCtrl">

     @Html.Partial("~/Views/Header/Index.cshtml")
     <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6">
          <div class="no-padding">
            <span class="title" style="padding-top: 20px;">CATEGORIES</span>
          </div>
          <a class ="list-group-item" ng-click="setActualItem($index)" ng-repeat="cat in categories">{{cat.name}}</a>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div id="ProductListcategory">
         ggfgfgfgfgf
         <div ng-repeat="p in products">
           <label>{{p.id}}</label>
           <label>{{p.name}}</label>
         </div>
     </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does console.log(data); output?

Comment: It prints in the console the datas. I analysed the datas and that's correct. I've the right datas in the array

Comment: Ok, perhaps Angular is not detecting that the data in the scope has changed.  Try calling $scope.$apply(); after you have assigned the data to the scope variable.

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work. When I execute $scope.apply(); or $scope.$apply(); , i've the following error : TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Try to initialize $scope.products to null just at controller instantiation. The $scope.apply should not be needed since we are calling $http, I have tried a plunkr with your code (no server call) and seems to be ok http://plnkr.co/edit/b0LPqYfbQRzUhDb3ATAF?p=preview I would try to be sure that the service is returning me a list of productos with id/name and no extra fields or structure.

Comment: Check js-console, you might be getting some js errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use angular.copy and define $scope.products on begining

```
var appli = angular.module("Demo", []);

appli.controller('CategoryCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

  $scope.products = [];
   $http.get('/Category/GetCategories')
        .success(
            function (data) {
              console.log(data);
              $scope.categories = data;
            }
         );

   $scope.setActualItem = function (index) {
      $scope.currentItem = $scope.categories[index];

      var idCat = $scope.currentItem.id;
      console.log("passe ici");
      $http.get('/Category/GetProductsByCategory/'+idCat)
           .success(
                function (data) {
                   console.log(data);


                   angular.copy(data,$scope.products);
                    //or angular.copy(data.data, $scope.products);
                }
            );
    };
});
```

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't nothing happen. Even with <div ng-repeat="p in products">
            {{p.id}}
            {{p.name}}
        </div>  p.id and p.name exists

Comment: you can check your data like in this way:                         <div id="ProductListcategory"><pre>{{products |json }}</pre> .... let's try and let me now what you've got

Comment: When I inspect the element "<div id="ProductListcategory>">" in Firefox, I've the following result : <div id="ProductListcategory">
        ggfgfgfgfgf
        <!-- ngRepeat: p in products -->

    </div>

Comment: I've tried the "<pre>{{products |json }}</pre>" but it doesn't happen. I've an empty array even if I click on a category and that I get the right datas after the ajax call. "<pre>{{products |json }}</pre>" returns an empty array

Comment: so console.log(data) print any data or not ?